# Design Reflection for business cards

Tags: business, reflection

I've designed a perspective view in which i show off my business card design. To make it realistic I want to use lightning conditions effectively.

In some Cards I they use beautiful *frosted glossy reflections*. here I'm giving you a link of an image. You will then understand what I need to know.

Check Out this: http://uflix.co.in/reflection.png

UPDATE:

Currently I use **Photoshop CS6** and here is what I've done till now: http://uflix.co.in/my-reflection.png

I need perfect visual appeal to my cards' design.

Comment: What have you tried? What programmes are you using? Show us what you have so far?

Comment: @boblet I use Photoshop CS6 to design.. Currently I use Gradients with one side sharp edge.

Comment: Quite similar to this question; http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/how-to-create-this-realistic-preview-of-a-business-card

Comment: Seems like a response to user568458's last comment on that question..

Comment: I answered the question that was similar to this one, it might help you http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/how-to-create-this-realistic-preview-of-a-business-card

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a gradient as a layer, use a layer mask with a distorted border.

Create a layer mask

[image]

Blur the edges

[image]

Distort the mask

[image]

Adjust layer opacity and blending. By using the 'Blend If...' Feature, you can knock out the edges of the card easily.

[image]

Clean up your mask edges, and adjust your lighting layer's colors

[image]