# Steps required to preview a glossy business card in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm new here. I have very little knowledge in Photoshop CC and I was hoping if one of you can help me. I have created a website and I need to include Business Card mockups created by me to the website. And even though I've managed to create the mockups, I'm having trouble with giving it a proper presentation effect. My requirement is to give it a realistic glossy effect to attract more users. I have currently gone through this link [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/how-to-create-this-realistic-glossy-preview-of-a-business-card) several times but have failed to accomplish the glossy effect. If anyone can please give me a step-by-step guide(with snapshots) on how to achieve this, it would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

This is where I've gotten so far:

[image: Glossy Business Card Mock]

Comment: Show us your attempt and where your stuck.

Comment: @Ryan You can check out what I've done so far [here](http://s1227.photobucket.com/user/fallen_angel53/library/Designs). As you can see the the white diagonal rectangle I have placed doesn't really bring out the glossy effect like in the link I have shared in the question. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by step instructions:

1. Set up your mockup. No gloss, no shadows.

[image]
2.

- Create a new layer above the card itself
- Fill it with black
- Take a preset brush (see image), change the color to white and paint a 'grunged' line.
- Then create a selection of your card layer (ctrl + leftclick on layer), invert selection (Alt + Shift + i) and press delete (the new created layer is still actively selected).
  [image]

  3. Glass filter
- Go to Filter > Distorsion > Glas and apply the settings from the screenshot
  [image]

  4. Transparency
- Set the layers mode to Screen (or Lighten) and set the opacity to ~20-30%
- Then create a new layer mask (Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal All)
- Select the gradient tool and create a gradient which fits your grunged line
  [image]