# How to create a 3D screenshot

Tags: 3d, screenshot

I'm trying to create a 3D version of a screenshot. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do that? I know somehow to do this in Photoshop? But I was wondering if there is a free software or online tool for this?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Photoshop? GIMP is free and you could use that. What have you tried though?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a tool that does this automatically? I mean gets the photo and creates the effect above.

Comment: You could create an action to do this automatically in Photoshop. I am sure you could also create the same action in GIMP. There might be an action already created for this. I doubt there is any online tools that would do this effect specifically, maybe something close to this.

Comment: @AndrewH Thank you so much, I will try to search more or right one myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create this realistic glossy preview of a business card?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/how-to-create-this-realistic-glossy-preview-of-a-business-card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right when you said Photoshop, and it's pretty easy, too. You have your screenshot, another one at the bottom turned 180° and erased a little plus some transparency for the reflection effect, then select both and transform with perspective and distort.

All you have to do now is play with a layer and a selection of your desired shadow colored black. Blur, eraser and stuff...

That'll be all, so if you get your hands on Photoshop, this is the way to do it.

PS: If you already have Photoshop, why not tackle this head on, rather than wasting time looking for a action on the internet or for a tool that will probably not do it exactly as you want? It's a simple process and for an experienced user it takes less than a minute. For someone with little Photoshop knowledge it will probably take 30 minutes but you will spend more trying to find a tool that generates this automatically. Just my opinion,  good luck with whatever approach you may choose.

Answer (score 2):

Vahid,
I'm sorry to say that the best tool to create such effect is probably Powerpoint... 
Copy/Paste the image inside a ppt presentation then add effect (reflection and 3d shadow), and then save everything in jpg.

[image: As you can see...]

And btw i think also open office can do something similar. 
Otherwise use photoshop, but it can be much more difficult to have the same effect.