# How to make printed paper depth-of-field effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, depth

Does anyone know where I can find a tutorial on how to make the graphic below? I'm not sure what it's called. A lot of times it really looks like it's been printed on paper and it's just a photograph. [This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9039/how-to-make-an-image-look-like-its-been-printed) article is helpful, but it is lacking the depth of field.

[image: depth of field effect on "printed" paper]

Comment: Try googling for "tilt shift"+photoshop

Comment: Filter > Blur Gallery > Tilt Shift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often your graphics software will already have the necessary tools for this effect:

1. Perspective transformation
2. Depth of field blur

For me good results can be achieved with the [G'MIC tools](https://gmic.eu/) that can be used in an [online version](https://gmicol.greyc.fr/), standalone, or as a plugin for Gimp.

From the online version upload any source image (here I used a screenshot of the Wikipedia article on Stack Exchange).

#### Filter > Deformations > Perspective

[image]

#### Filter > Degradation > Blur [depth-of-field]

[image]

Play with the settings rulers to achieve desired effect strength.

Below I added a canvas effect and ripple transformation with rather exaggerated values for illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start with a basic shot, then edit > transform > perspective and pinch the top in. Then rotate a a little. Then copy the layer and apply a gaussian blur to that new layer.

Now of course it is all blurred. Then put a gradient mask on the blurred layer to clear the "Focus" (gradually delete the blur layer) in the top area.

The trick you are missing here is that it's not really "depth of field". It's just a gaussian blur fading out from the bottom to the top.